# How do viewpager images as app "Mercado Livre" and others

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, material-design

I would like to ask your help on how to do this layout that neither the "Mercado Livre" (Name from app in portuguese Brazil) and other app out there, how real "Viva Real Imoveis" (Name from app in portuguese Brazil). The layout I need is equal to this I'm putting down, it would be a toolbar in the same way and just under one view pager with those balls that pass the images and clicking on the images they're in fullscreen and continue with indicator balls. Below view pager pictures I put the rest of my layout. The main part of you that need help that would be it, the slide images with drag finger counter with balls and fullscreen too. Design material.

Could help me?

[image: Slide images]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator.java) you have mate. Maybe you'll need customize a little the drawables.